# How to create a function WordSplit(strArr) read the array of strings stored in strArr using dart

Tags: dart

I have a simple exercise in Coderbyte, it just want to have a function that's WordSplit(strArr) read the array of strings stored in strArr, For example I have two elements like ["hellocat", "apple,bat,cat,goodbye,hello,yellow,why"]

I just want to to determine if the first element in the input can be split into two words, where both words exist in the dictionary that is provided in the second input.

For example: the first element can be split into two words: hello and cat because both of those words are in the dictionary.

So the program should return the two words that exist in the dictionary separated by a comma, as this result `hello,cat` .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>

using namespace std;

vector<string> converToWords(string dict) {

    vector<string> res;
    string s = "";
    int n = dict.length();
    for(int i=0; i<n; i++) {
        if(dict[i] == ',') {
            res.push_back(s);
            s = "";
        }
        else s += dict[i];
    }
    res.push_back(s);
    s = "";
    return res;
}

string solve(string str[]) {

    string result = "";
    string word = str[0], dict = str[1];
    int n = word.length();
    vector<string> vs = converToWords(dict);
    unordered_set<string> ust;
    for(auto it: vs) ust.insert(it);
    // for(auto i=ust.begin(); i!=ust.end(); i++){
    //     cout<<*i<<endl;
    // }
    string s = "";
    for(int i=0; i<n; i++) {
        s += word[i];
        // cout<<s<<endl;
        string temp = word.substr(i+1, n-(i+1));
        // cout<<temp<<endl;
        if(ust.find(s) != ust.end() && ust.find(temp) != ust.end()) {
            cout<<s<<endl;
            cout<<temp<<endl;
            result += s+","+temp;
            break;
        }
        temp = "";
    }
    return result;
}

int main() {

    string arr[2];
    cin>>arr[0]>>arr[1];
    cout << solve(arr);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Code is a lot more helpful when it is accompanied by an explanation. Stack Overflow is about learning, not providing snippets to blindly copy and paste. Please [edit] your question and explain how it answers the specific question being asked. See [answer].

Answer (score 1):

I've made a recursive solution below. It checks if the string to be split starts with any word in the dictionary. If it exists, the function is called again using a substring with that first word removed.

This function only works up to the first word that isn't in the dictionary since you did not specify the expected behavior when the inputted word is not made up of words in the dictionary. You could make it throw an exception perhaps, but please specify your expectation.

```dart
void main() {
  print(wordSplit(["hellocat", "apple,bat,cat,goodbye,hello,yellow,why"]));
  //hello,cat
}

String wordSplit(List<String> arg) {
  String wordToSplit = arg[0];
  String dict = arg[1];
  List<String> parsedDict = arg[1].split(',');
  
  for(String word in parsedDict) {
    if(wordToSplit.startsWith(word)) {
      //If the substring would be empty, don't do more recursion
      if(word.length == wordToSplit.length) {
        return word;
      }
      return word + ',' + wordSplit([wordToSplit.substring(word.length), dict]);
    }
  }
  return wordToSplit;
}
```

Comment: It does not return the expected result for `["baseball", "a,all,b,ball,bas,base,cat,code,d,e,quit,z"]`: `base,ball`.

Answer (score 0):

Worked on this yesterday, and this algorithm below will give you the required answer

```
    String wordSplit(List arg) { 

      String wordToSplit = arg[0];
      String searchWords = arg[1];
      List<String> searchList = searchWords.split(',');
  
      for(String word in  searchList){
         if(wordToSplit.startsWith(word)){
                  if(word.length == wordToSplit.length){
                      return word;
                  }
                  //Check if word found is at least half the word to 
                  //split length
                  if(word.length >= wordToSplit.length / 2){
                     return word + ',' + wordSplit([wordToSplit.substring(word.length), searchWords]); 
              }
              
          } 
  }
  
  return arg[0];
}
```